# Run Backgroung thread , when activity is created

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am new to Android Programming. I am making an App which requires "OnlineMode" as well as "OfflineMode". I researched a lot about the topic and first step is to check for internet connectivity continously. Just like big apps like "WhatsApp" "Hike" etc use. Now I tried to create a thread which will run in background , it got created but not being able to produce the output the results. I have tried various methods. Here's what i want

**1. A thread should run continuously on the background throughout the app checking the network connectivity.**

**2. Thread should be created as soon as user opens up the app**

Below is my MainActivity.java file

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;    


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    // flag for Internet connection status
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

    // Connection detector class
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       runInBackground();

       Button btnStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_check);

        btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

   void runInBackground() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ConnectivityManager cm =
                        (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                        activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
                if (!isConnected) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Thread t1 = new Thread(this);
                            t1.start();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are online.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            runInBackground();
                        }
                    });
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have gone offline.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(6000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    runInBackground();
                }
            }
        });
    }                

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

*Edit:*
Here is my final code  and i am getting errors

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xyz.broadcastreciever" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- Internet Permissions -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <!-- Network State Permissions -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        NetworkChangeReceiver network = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
        network.onReceive(this,intent);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**NetworkChangeReceiver.java**

public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {

        Log.d("Netowk Available ", "Flag No 1");
    }
}
```

}

**And Here is my Logs showing errors:**

```
02-19 12:10:21.321  30369-30369/com.aubergine.broadcastreciever E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aubergine.broadcastreciever/com.aubergine.broadcastreciever.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10208 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10208 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
            at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:1123)
            at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:636)
            at com.aubergine.broadcastreciever.NetworkChangeReceiver.onReceive(NetworkChangeReceiver.java:19)
            at com.aubergine.broadcastreciever.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ***"A thread should run continuously on the background throughout the app checking the network connectivity."*** this is a very bad approach to check for network connectivity again and again you can use `BroadcastReceivers` for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the internet connectivity you should not start a new thread instead of this follow these steps:

1. As soon as you enter the app check for internet connectivity.
2. Add a BroadCastREceiver that keeps on listening to network on/off i.e state change updates for that add a IntentFilter `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />`
3. Now whenever you are connected or disconnected to the internet you will receive a update in onReceive of your BroadcastReceiver.

This is the receiver in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

This is the java class of receiver:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {
            // Do something

            Log.d("Netowk Available ", "Flag No 1");
        }
    }
}
```

If you are stuck in any of above step please comment.

Comment: This looks great , i'll try it and if i face any issues along the way i'll make sure to comment !! Meanwhile can u please provide me a link to a good tutorial to this !!

Comment: While everything is in the answer but if you want to look in to the documentation this http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html will provide you the best documentation of network status. If you find the answer useful please mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: I am still not so sure what to write in MainActivity.java file !! for more understanding purpose , open the link 
http://www.hastebin.com/iwokexozof.avrasm

Comment: you just check the internet in the MainActivity.java and the receiver will notify you on the network status change. If you want to do it for your activity only then make the receiver as inner class of your activity and register and unregister it in onResume and onPause respectively and do activity related work in onReceive